# Savon returning NoMethodError error

Tags: ruby, soap, savon

I'm new to Savon, getting `configure_headers': undefined method`%' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) error when trying to send a soap request
my code looks like this

```
client = Savon.client do
  wsdl "http://sfds:9080/f/sca/BrokerService/WEBINF/wsdl/client/BrokerService_BrokerService.wsdl"
  soap_version "2"
end

response =  client.call(:get_broker_details, message: { brokerId: 'testbroker' })
```

Request through SoapUI looks like this

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
 xmlns:oas="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-
 wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
 xmlns:xyz="http://xml.bnz.co.nz/bnzintegrationcommon/BNZServiceHeadeV120" 
 xmlns:brok="http://xml.xyz.co.nz/brokerservice/BrokerService">
   <soap:Header>
     <oas:Security>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <oas:UsernameToken>
        <oas:Username></oas:Username>
        <oas:Password></oas:Password>
     </oas:UsernameToken>
  </oas:Security>
     <x:serviceHeaderV120>
     <user>
        <channel>BKLP</channel>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <id idType="staffId">631447</id>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <subId></subId>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <location>BRCH0573</location>
     </user>
     <application>
        <id>1</id>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <correlationToken>11111</correlationToken>
     </application>
  </x:serviceHeaderV120>
</soap:Header>
 <soap:Body>
    <brok:getBrokerDetails>
       <getBrokerDetailsRequest>
         <brokerId>ZS1002</brokerId>
       </getBrokerDetailsRequest>
    </brok:getBrokerDetails>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

will highly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [section of source code that the stack trace points to](https://github.com/savonrb/savon/blob/73eb888b7f896d5bd0551971d26436b4eb90afd2/lib/savon/request.rb#L76-L107), the reason for the error is fairly easy to work out:

```
CONTENT_TYPE = {
  1 => "text/xml;charset=%s",
  2 => "application/soap+xml;charset=%s"
}

# ...

# This line was the cause of the error:
@http_request.headers["Content-Type"] ||= CONTENT_TYPE[@globals[:soap_version]] % @globals[:encoding]
```

The error stems from the fact that you set `soap_version "2"` (a **`String`**) in your client. Instead, as you can see from the hash above, it needs to be an **`Integer`**:

```
client = Savon.client do
  wsdl "http://sfds:9080/f/sca/BrokerService/WEBINF/wsdl/client/BrokerService_BrokerService.wsdl"
  soap_version 2 # <-- !!!
end
```

This subtle fact [is documented](http://savonrb.com/version2/globals.html) by the library.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Tom. It fixed my problem.